# Impedance matching for inductively powering / rectifier

Tags: rectifier, passive-networks, resonance, matching

I have two questions.

1. If the receiver is inductively powered (by LC resonator) and needs a matching network in front of the RF-to-DC rectifier, what kind of quality factor of matching network (or Qs of the capacitor and coil inductance) should I expect? Assume the inductive powering frequency is at 500 MHz.
2. Since there is a load at the output of rectifier to withdraw the current/power from the resonator, is it a low Q system in nature? If so, will it affect the selection of matching network component precision?

I am quite confused and cannot find some convincing answers. Any insight will be much appreciated. Please correct me if any concept in my description is not right.

Comment: "*If the receiver ...*". What receiver? A radio receiver? A line receiver? Radio isn't mentioned anywhere in the title, question or tags. Can you edit your question to clarify? Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Any power drawn from a resonator lowers its Q, damping it. This is fundamental.

Comment: Do you really want Wireless power transferred (WPT) at 500MHz?  Since the load is capacitive when switched on and open when off, it may resemble a pulsed load of low Q when power is received and high Q when not. Max power transfer may be achieved when coupling matches source and load impedance using active PFC and high Q isolated coils on both sides with low turns ratio conducted giving a Z transform to free space on both sides.

Comment: Do you have some specific part numbers in mind that you could share?